# How may I calculate a cumulative z score from multiple z scores - vector autoregression?

Tags: autoregressive

I ran a vector autoregression (var) on a set of 64 companies with at least 6 data points in each company (lags 1, 2 ,3). I got the results of all 64 companies into one table and was able to calculate the mean coefficients but how can i compute a single z score and a p value for this table? I have individual z scores and p values for the 64 companies but i need to get one z score and p value.

I have the following formula
 =1√N* summation(i=j to k) (t(j)/√k(j)/k(j)-2)
where tj is the t-statistic for firm j associated with the estimate of the parameter, kj is degrees of freedom in the regression for firm j, and N is the number of firms in the sample. But I have no degrees of freedom in my sample so I cannot use that formula.

Can anyone suggest what I can do?

Regards